# How to get all the related ids without array?

Tags: post-meta, wpdb

I want to get all the post ids when the post meta includes a key of "project_id". This function get the job down, but need refine:

```
function get_all_ids(){
global $wpdb, $post;
$meta_key1 = 'project_id';
$postids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT key1.post_id
    FROM $wpdb->postmeta key1
    WHERE key1.meta_key = %s",$meta_key1 ) );
return $postids;
}
```

This returns arrays of (0 =>1), ( 1 =>3 ), (2 =>5)
In the later step, I will need to get the ids like this:

```
$this->results = $projects->get_all_ids();
```

This requires the ids are not arrays. How can I get all the ids without array?

Comment: In what format do you expect to have the list of ids?

Comment: I'm not sure. I am trying to make a loop for an object which attached to each post. If has ids, the loop will start. When there is an id, I can get data from a class.

Comment: If there is a loop that process those ids then array is the best format, but if you can show us that loop then we will actually know in what format does the loop expects the result.

Comment: the loop is too long, this comment box not allow.

Comment: ok, find a way-- this is the original loop: https://github.com/kunalb/EventPress/blob/master/views/kb-loop.php , I will make an extends of this kb-loop for my object.

Comment: `class MP_Objects extends KB_Loop {
function MP_objects( $args ) {
global $mp_projects;
$this->results = $mp_projects->get_all_ids(); //this is the ids 
}
function id() {
return $this->result->ID;
}
function graph( $args, $mp_object ) {
$defaults = Array(
'item_id' => $this->result->ID,
//and other matters
);
if ( $mp_object ){
//...
}
return mp_draw_graph( $args );
}
}
`

Answer (score 1):

If you need the ids separated by coma you can get them from the array you have:

```
$listids = implode ( "," , $postids );
```

In any case, please provide more info or code about what you need

Comment: would you please take a look at the loop I posted in the above comment?

Comment: I want the formate llike this: 'project id' => 1,'height'=>x,'width'=>y